# Style with arrow when mouse hover on button, wpf

Tags: wpf, image, xaml, button, mouseevent

I had a `Image` and `Button` like this in WPF:

```
<Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="31.627" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="32" Margin="21,80.373,0,0" Source="Images\computer.png"/>
<Button FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="12" Content=swethapilli" Height="31.627" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="57,80.373,95.296,0"/>
```

Now it appears like this:

[image]

Now my requirement is when mouse hover on the `Image` or `Button`. the text (swethapilli) should move to right and highlight when the arrow image appears same as like the below image.

[image: it should appear like this]

How to get this style can any one please help me to find the solution. Thank you.

Comment: Image is part of your button ?

Comment: no i have prepared only the arrow image by using geometry drawing

Comment: i mean the image in above pic.

Comment: yes.. it should be the part of button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to create an image which you can use as button background when mouse is over, like so:

```
    <Style x:Key="SwitchButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="yourimagepath.ending"></ImageBrush>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Right"/>
            </Trigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
     </Style>
```

EDIT: A more flexible way to position your content is the following:

Take a TextBlock as buttons content:

```
            <Button.Content>
                <TextBlock Text="YourTextOrBinding" Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=TextBlockOnButtonStyle}"></TextBlock>
            </Button.Content>
```

TextBlockOnButtonStyle:

```
    <Style x:Key="TextBlockOnButtonStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Button}}, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,0,0,0"></Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

The 10 in the setters value is the number of pixels which the text goes to the right if the mouse is over the button.

EDIT 2: If you want to use a rectangle instead of the whole image as buttons background, you can do it like so:

```
        <DockPanel Width="100" Height="30">
            <Rectangle Visibility="{Binding ElementName=btnMain, Path=IsMouseOver, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=BoolToVis}}" Width="25">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <whateveryouwanttousetofilltheimage>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <Button Name="btnMain" Content="YourContentOrBinding"/>
        </DockPanel>
```

Here I bound the Visibility of the rectangle to the buttons IsMouseOver-property and converted the output with the BooleanToVisibilityConverter.

Comment: thank you for your comment. Here you have changed the background and replace with image. i prepared the image for arrow. But how can i combine the image with rectangle and rectangle width same as content of the button.

Comment: Why do you need a rectangle?

Comment: i thought of rectangle to combine with arrow image as i dont need the arrow to appear seperately when mouse hover on the button.

Comment: Why dont you make an image which consists of the gray field, the arrow and the blue field? So you wouldnt need a rectangle.

Comment: Unless the image is vector, probably don't want to be using images for this.  It won't scale with DPI changes.